# DB Connection Error

Tags: database, error, domain

My site was pointed to an IP without an attached domain. Now that the domain is pointed there, the pages stopped resolving and I get an error 500 message. After some trouble shooting I found:

A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/EE_Config.php

Line Number: 207

which points to:

```
$query = ee()->db->get_where('sites', array('site_id' => $site_id));
```

I have looked at the database config file and nothing seems wrong. I took out the direct IP links and it now points to the domain. No usernames or passwords changed so any idea on what needs modifying?

Answer (score 1):

Is the database on the same server as the files? if so, many hosting providers allow you to just use "localhost" for the host name value in a connection. Have you tried that?

Does it work if you change it back to the IP?